# Trouble Setting Up SSH Keys for Git in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ssh, github

I'm following the instructions on Github for installing the SSH Keys, but after I enter the passphrase twice, I keep getting this message in the terminal, "open .../.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory."

Is this a permissions thing or something? I'm trying to do this from my company user account and not my admin account.

Comment: Have you generated keys with ssh-keygen first?

Comment: Yes. I did the ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my email" just like in the Github instructions

Comment: what does 'ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa' have to say for itself? Or perhaps you need to expand your message to show exactly what commands you are running, and the url of the github instructions you are following.

Comment: Here's the page of instructions I'm following: http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/. I seem to be stuck in the middle of #3.

Comment: are you cd'd into .ssh? Do you even have a .ssh directory?

Comment: Am just following the instructions to the letter on that page. I tried do mkdir .ssh, but it came back with Permission denied

Comment: Now you've revealed the issue. How do you not have write access to create a .ssh in your own home directory?

Comment: I have no idea. The account I'm signed into is one that I migrated from my MacBook over to my new iMac. Not sure if that could affect permissions?

Comment: This is now definitively off topic. Please open a question at superuser or the mac site about your access control problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an `ssh-add` after step 3 to store the key locally, it is required before pushing anything to git. Solved it for Mac OSX 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to resolve I just took the default suggestion for the .ssh folder and i changed my passphrase to a one word passphrase (no spaces). This worked for me, I didn;t have to mess with permissions or anything. Hope you get it sorted.